# Locating Cells in RDLC Files

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I've inherited a pretty big report. The RDLC file is over 11,200 lines of XML.

In Visual Studio, it is easy to find the relevant element for a bound value in the raw xml (simple Find operation).

Is there a way to find that cell in the visual designer?
For example, if I know the cell has a TextBox with a name SupervisionLevelName61, is there a quick and easy way to locate that in the Visual Designer view of that RDLC file? Perhaps a keyboard shortcut which gives that cell focus?

Obviously, manually searching for that cell, given the name of the Textbox, takes far too long owing to the sheer size of the RDLC file.

Thanks

Comment: That is a good question. I also would be interested in an answer to that. I upvoted your question.

Comment: I am interested in knowing as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

At the top of the properties window you have a dropdown field. Within this dropdown field you see all the the elements within your current section (in my example I'm in the document body).

[image]

When you click an item, the design-view will focus the item like in the next screenshot (see the orange bracket).

[image]

Comment: Nice work and thank you very much. This is very much appreciated! Be well.